# Parent item click firing in ToolStripMenu

Tags: c#, windows

I am using the toolStripMenu in my C#.net windows application.

I have added one ToolStripSplitButton in toolStripMenu, 
this button is having its click event implemented and having 2 items 
fist is "Save" second is "Delete" and Click event implemented for both items.

when I run the application and click on toolStripMenu button drop-down icon (triangular icon to get its child item) the ToolStripSplitButton [image: click event is firing] I suppose it should be fire only when i click on toolstrip button not on its drop down icon.

Please suggest me how can I handle it.

Comment: You mean share my desktop or send print screen of from ?

Comment: yes, i cannot imagine how your ui is built

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var button = new ToolStripSplitButton("Save", "path to Save image");
button.ButtonClick += clickEventHandler;
```

The ToolStripSplitButton has two click handlers. One is called "Click" and the other is called "ButtonClick". The `clickEventHandler` in this constructor `new ToolStripSplitButton("Save", "path to Save image", clickEventHandler)` is the "Click" handler and fires no matter where on the control you click. The "ButtonClick" handler only fires when you click the button itself, not the drop down icon.